# EntityManager em.remove() and em.persist() not reflected in same context while changes in Entity are reflected

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, persist

I am calling a

```
 SomeEntity someEntity = em.find(EntityPK.Class,entityPK);
 em.Remove(entityPK);
```

and then persist on same primary key

```
 em.persist(someEntity)
```

SQLIntegrityContraintViolatinException is thrown that entity with primary key already exist.

while if I changes

```
someEntity.setName("Test");
```

and then gets the same entity back with

```
someEntity = em.find(EntityPK.Class,entityPK);
```

it gives me back updated someEntity with

```
 someEntity.getName()
```

returns 'Test'.

Changes in the someEntity are reflected while its removal is not reflected.

I am new to the JPA and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reincarnating objects is normally not a good idea.  It is better to use a new id for a new object, such as a generated id.

If you must reincarnate and object, try doing it in a separate transaction, or at least call flush() after the remove to delete it from the database first.

Comment: called em.flush() after em.remove() and problem got resolved.